# Two Different IP Address - Cross domain Issue

Tags: cross-domain, ip-address

We have developed web portal in Spring MVC. We add our own flash player in our portal. 
We want to play a video from another one server. 
When we try to play a video it shows crossdomain error. 
How do we solve this issue.

Faster Reply is much appreciated. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to include cross-domain.xml under Root folder in Server

cross-domain.xml should contain the following content:
**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- http://www.osmf.org/crossdomain.xml -->
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

**